# URL to map application

Tags: android, iphone, hyperlink, href

In a web page I can make a link like `<a href="tel:3035551212">Information</a>` and clicking that will dial that number of the web page is displayed in a browser on a phone.

Is there a url that will open the phone's map application at a specific location, optionally also specifying the address at that location?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme